# C# Assign Name to integer (to generate a unique integer)

Tags: c#, int, variable-assignment

I have:

```
var ItemName = "Item_1_Type_0";
int Stock = 2;
```

I want to generate an integer Name using var Item Name and then assign int value "int Stock"
something like:

```
int Item_1_Type_0 = Stock;
```

and after that i need a way to check if stock is bigger than 0

```
if( Item_1_Type_0 > 0 ){ 
   // do something 
} //(here i need the encoded variable to replace my example "Item_1_Type_0")
```

Comment: This is **bad bad bad** practice. You either need a class or a collection (possibly both). NEVER "number" your variables. Either way this is not possible, dynamic variable names are not allowed in C#

Comment: Bradley is right, though I have the feeling that you're just not stating your problem/question very clearly. You're asking about how to do one specific thing, which is probably a bad idea. But what is the problem you're actually trying to solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use a dictionary instead?

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();
dictionary.Add("Item_1_Type_0" , Stock);
```

Then:

```
if(dictionary["Item_1_Type_0"] > 0)
```